# Print on the back of front page in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have created a document in Indesign with facing pages. I want to print with page 2 on the back of page the front page. Is there a way to do that?
I even export the document to pdf and printed it from there. But even there it always puts the back side of the front page as an empty one...

---

I am just printing it on a regular A4 paper, and I set it to print in both sides. But then the problem occurs

Comment: What do you mean by ‘the back of the front page’? How are you printing the document? If you’re just printing on regular A4 paper, you just need to set the printer to print on both sides, that should do it; if you’re getting it offset printed, it’s a lot more complicated since covers are printed separately. But we need more details to help you, because as it is we have no idea what your workflow or desired result really is.

Comment: In InDesign, page 2 is the "back of the front page".

Comment: Is your printer capable of printing on both sides?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a printer capable of printing on both sides, check the printer settings and how that works.

Otherwise, go basic: print page 1, then, put the paper back into the printer, white side facing up, and print page 2.

Comment: Bad idea to flip an already printed page if the printer is a laser printer and is *not* capable of duplex printing, it'll ruin the fuser.... not so much an issue for inkjets though.

Comment: Ok. Was not aware of this, been printing a ton of front & back pages on my laser b/w printer.

Comment: Yeah it works.. but it drastically shortens the life of the fuser.